# Problems with decode UTF8

Tags: php, utf

I tried everything to solve the problem and still do not know, commas above the letters yes but the hooks above the letters no. please help, sample code. Everything works on the web, but when I add items I have a ->? But in the database I have hooks and commas as it should be.

```
     $connect = new PDO("mysql:host=****;dbname=******_eshop", "*****_eshop", "C3*****e");

      $query = "SELECT * FROM produkt_sklen_dary ORDER BY id DESC";
     header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
     $statement = $connect->prepare($query);

      if($statement->execute())
     {
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
$output = '';
foreach($result as $row)
{

    $output .= '
    <div class="col-md-3" style="margin-top:12px;">  
        <div style="border:1px solid #333; background-color:#f1f1f1; border-radius:5px; padding:16px; height:auto;" align="center">
        <img src="fotky_sklendary/'.$row["fotka"].'" class="img-responsive" /><br />
            <h4 class="text-info">'.utf8_encode($row["jmeno"]).'</h4>
            <h4 class="text-danger">CZK '.$row["cena"] .'</h4>
            <div contenteditable="false" style="color:#595959">'.utf8_encode($row["popis"]).'</div>
            <input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity' . $row["id"] .'" class="form-control" value="1" />
            <input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" id="name'.$row["id"].'" value="'.utf8_encode($row["jmeno"]).'" />
            <input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" id="price'.$row["id"].'" value="'.$row["cena"].'" />
            <input type="button" name="add_to_cart" id="'.$row["id"].'" style="margin-top:5px;" class="btn btn-success form-control add_to_cart" value="Přidat do košíku" />
        </div>
    </div>
    ';
}
echo $output;
```

Next using

```
  <script>  
   $(document).ready(function(){

load_product();

load_cart_data();

function load_product()
{
    $.ajax({
        url:"fetch_itemglassgifts.php",
        type:"POST",

        success:function(data)
        {
            $('#display_item').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of desired output and actual output? It's not entirely clear what's wrong.

Comment: Check what DB returns to you, check what encoding connection accepts. Better set it explicitly: via `header('Content-type: …');` and `SET NAMES utf8;`.

Comment: I have utf8 in the database but it shows -? I have already try this option and did not help